# Remove a tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove the first occurrence of a tag e.g "p" tag that appears above an element, now this tag can either be directly above it (previous sibling) or it could be parent's previous sibling. I would like to do this in jQuery

```
<p>..</p>
<span>abcd</span>

<p>..</p>
<div>
<span>abcd</span>
```

in both the cases I would like to remove the p tag from span's perspective.

Comment: Does the structure is always the same? one of the previous elements or one of the parent's previous elements?

Comment: Nah, It could be grandparents sibling or even higher up, but i need to remove the first p tag i see above the element i am working on.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a quick solution here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an element's closest previous `<p>` sibling using the [`.prevAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) together with [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/). If the result is a non-empty jQuery object then you (obviously) have a match, so remove it.

If the result is an empty jQuery object then there wasn't a matching sibling, so try the same thing starting from the current span's parent, using a loop to keep going up the tree as far as needed.

(If you only want to test the element's *immediate* sibling then use `.prev("p")` instead of `prevAll("p").first()`.)

```js
$("span").click(function() {
  // not sure how you're getting a reference to the starting span element,
  // but assuming for demonstration purposes it is 'this' in an event handler
  var current = $(this);
  var prev;

  while (!current.is("body")) {
    prev = current.prevAll("p").first();
    if (prev.length > 0) {
      prev.remove();
      break;
    }
    current = current.parent();
  }
});
```

```css
div { border: thin black solid; margin: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>abcd</span>
<p>..</p>
<span>abcd</span>

<p>..</p>
<div>
  <span>abcd</span>
</div>
<div>
  <p>..</p>
  <div>a div</div>
  <span>abcd</span>
</div>
<p>..</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>abcd</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this demo is what you're looking for, but this maybe the case:

You will have to loop all `p` tags and check if it has a `next()` sibling and remove it and break the loop.

see this **DEMO**:

```js
// loop all p's
$('p').each(function(ndx, elem) {
    // if element has a next sibling
    if ($(elem).next().length > 0) {
     console.log('removed :', $(elem).text());

     $(elem).remove(); // remove this <p> tag
       return false; // break out of loop
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>first p of body</p>
<div class="container">
    <p>first p of container div</p>
    <span>abcd</span>
</div>

<p>second p of body</p>
<span>abcd</span>

<p>third p of body</p>
<div>
<span>abcd</span>
```

Comment: no, this is not what i want, i actually need to remove the p if it is elder sibling of a particular span or an elder sibling to span's ancester

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to delete `p` tag that is previous sibling of `span` tag's parent where parent can be any levels above `span`.

Check this script:

```js
function isPTag($el) {
  return $el.prop("tagName").toUpperCase() === 'P';
}

function removeIfPTag($el) {
  if ($el.length > 0 && isPTag($el)) {
    $el.remove();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function removeClosePTag($el) {
  function removePrevious($el) {
    var previous = $el.prevAll();
    for (var j = 0; j < previous.length; j += 1) {
      current = $(previous[j]);
      if (removeIfPTag(current)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

    // Finds `p` in previous elements relative `span`
  if (removePrevious($el)) {
    return true;
  }
  var parents = $el.parents();
  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i += 1) {
    var current = $(parents[i]);
    if (removeIfPTag(current)) {
      return true;
    }

    // Finds `p` in previous elements relative to `current` (one of span's parents)
    if (removePrevious(current)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


console.log(removeClosePTag($('#first-span')));
console.log(removeClosePTag($('#second-span')));
console.log(removeClosePTag($('#third-span')));
console.log(removeClosePTag($('#fourth-span')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>first p (should remain)</p>
  <p>second p (should delete)</p>
  <div>
    <span id="first-span">first span</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="second-span">second span</span>
  <p>(should remain)</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>third p (should delete)</p>
  <span id="third-span">first span</span>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <p>fourth p (should remain)</p>
  </div>
  <span id="fourth-span">fourth span</span>
</div>
```

Notice how **fourth p** is not removed even though it's above `#fourth-span`. If you want to remove it then you would have to go through the entire DOM tree above initial `span` element which would be expensive for CPU and might easily hang browser.